# If $n^k$ is odd, $n$ is odd (proof by contra-positive)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I started with the claim that: If $n$ is even, $n^k$ is even.

But I have only gotten this far:
$$n = 2a,$$
$$n^k = (2a)^k,$$
$$n^k = 2^k a^k.$$

I am trying to reach the format where I can show that
$$n^k = 2a,$$
so that $n^k$ is even.

Comment: $n^k = 2^k a^k = 2(2^{k-1} a^k)$

Comment: Shouldn't a proof by contrapositive be that if $n^k$ is odd, then $n$ is odd?

Comment: @player3236 thank you !

Comment: @JustinYoung yes sorry I made a mistake in the title it should be "if n^k is odd then n is odd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use your solution. Let's assume that $n$ is even, then we can write
$$n=2a.$$
Powering the both sides we obtain
$$n^k=(2a)^k=2^ka^k.$$
Taking $a'=2^{k-1}a^k$ we have
$$n^k=(2a)^k=2^ka^k=2\cdot 2^{k-1}a^k=2a',$$
so $n^k$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

$$n=2m\iff n^k=2p$$ where $p=2^{k-1}m^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using modular arithmetic.

We have that if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, then $n^k \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$. So if $n$ is even, then $n^k$ must also be even.

Hence if $n^{k}$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k>1$, pos. integer.

Assume $n$ is even, i. e. $2|n$ or $n=2r$ pos. integer.

$n^k=nn^{k-1}=(2r)n^{k-1}=2(rn^{k-1})$, i.e. $n^k$ is divisible by $2$, even.